# Migrating to iText 7 - Adding generic object to PDF

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I need to add a generic PdfObject to a PDF without putting it in the document anywhere.

Here's the code from iText 5 that works:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(args[0]);

PdfLiteral obj = new PdfLiteral("HelloWorld");
PdfArray arr = new PdfArray();
arr.add(obj);
reader.addPdfObject(arr);

OutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(args[0] + "-itext5.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fout);
stamper.close();
fout.close();
reader.close();
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in iText 7 (there is no addPdfObject method):

```
try (PdfDocument writer = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(args[0]), new PdfWriter(args[0] + "-itext7.pdf"))) {
    PdfLiteral obj = new PdfLiteral("HelloWorld");
    PdfArray arr = new PdfArray();
    arr.add(obj);
    // method 1:
    arr.copyTo(writer);
    // method 2:
    arr.makeIndirect(writer);
}
```

However, the array is not in the PDF after I close it.  I think I remember Bruno mentioning somewhere that iText 7 now removes unused objects on close, similar to PdfReader.removeUnusedObjects() in iText 5.

Is there a way to add the object to the XRef dictionary, and add it into the PDF, without referencing it anywhere, as was done in iText 5?

Alternatively, is there a safe place to add an unused PdfName in the Catalog or somewhere else that won't affect viewers in any way?  I'm unclear on the PDF spec here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iText7 indeed by default does not write unused objects to the output document.

There are at least two ways to implement your use case of writing a dangling object to the document.

**Option 1**

Use `PdfDocument#setFlushUnusedObjects` method to always flush unused objects. The rest of the code you have is correct and stays as is:

```
pdfDocument.setFlushUnusedObjects(true);

PdfLiteral obj = new PdfLiteral("HelloWorld");
PdfArray arr = new PdfArray();
arr.add(obj);
arr.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
```

**Option 2**

Flush the object you want immediately and explicitly with `PdfObject#flush`. This does not change default logic for removing unused objects, so any objects you haven't called `flush()` on will still be removed.

```
PdfLiteral obj = new PdfLiteral("HelloWorld");
PdfArray arr = new PdfArray();
arr.add(obj);
arr.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
arr.flush();
```

Comment: Thank you!  The both worked equally well for me.  I chose option 2 so I can flush the object locally when needed, and not have to affect the entire document.